# Unexpected error in driver invocation: fatalError

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Xcode shows Unexpected error in driver invocation: fatalError on building[image]

Answer (score 18):

I've tried to run the project on my another computer with the same version of xcode and it turns out I have duplicate filename ))). Stupid xcode!!!